# Json data weird behavior

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am experincing some weird behavior when loadin json data via ajax with an interval.
The data loads fine, only after a few intervals the data scrambles and keeps running between intervals. This even causes the browser to crash

html page

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function ahitRate() 
{
    $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'average.php',
    data: 'jsonData',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
            {
                var ahr = data[0];              //get id
                var hitRate = data[1];           //get name
                $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+ahr+"<b> name:   </b>"+hitRate); 
                setInterval(ahitRate, 5000);
                }           
    });
}); 
</script>
```

json php code that generates random data

    

`// Session
session_start();

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

$y = rand(0, 100);

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array("Average", $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>`

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: show a sample json coming from the php

Comment: @shyju 
the json output is

[
   "Average hit rate",
   20
]

where the number is the random string generated by php

Answer (score 2):

OMG!

You are calling this recursively!

```
setInterval(ahitRate, 5000);
```

EDIT: simply change setInterval(...) to setTimeout(ahitRate, 5000);

Every time it executes, the old one keeps going and a new one is added, so it will use more and more memory!

```
$(function() {
    function ahitRate() 
    {
         $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         url: 'average.php',
         data: 'jsonData',
         dataType: 'json',
         processData: false,
         success: function(data)
                    {
                         var ahr = data[0];              //get id
                         var hitRate = data[1];           //get name
                         $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+ahr+"<b> name:   </b>"+hitRate); 
                         }           
         });
    } 

    setInterval(ahitRate, 5000);

});
```

The only different is that I:

1. removed the setInterval(...) method from inside the ajax success function
2. called it exactly one time at the end of the closure (the "$(function() { ... } );"

This will cause your "ahitRate()" function to be invoked every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, I have pushed the changes you have made above but the strange behavior is still occurring.

Comment: it is working correctly, the old page was still cached by my browser.
Thnx for the help!!

Comment: sweet! make sure to accept the answer if it fixed your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

setInterval keeps firing - and each time you get a new response you start a new timer. So after five seconds the first timer fires and starts another. Then after ten seconds BOTH timers fire, and start two more.

I think you can see where this is going.

I think you're looking for the setTimeout() method, or just start your interval timer outside the success function, so it never gets called again.